# Make no change in else with inline loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a inline loop that finds < 3 in a column of counts . I would like to change a different column when this is true and make no changes when it is not true.

I don't know what to put in the else to make no change to df["TOTAL']

I tied it with a for loop but this does not work because if any rows are less then 3 it changes all the rows.

```py
df['TOTAL'] = [np.nan if x > 3 else ?? for x in df['COUNT_MONTHS']]
```

```py
for x in df['COUNT_MONTHS']:   
    if x < 3:   
       df['TOTAL'] = np.nan
```

Comment: you need to use that index you are getting.

Comment: I don't use pandas, so I know there is probably a more correct way to do this, but this works: `df['TOTAL'][df['COUNT_MONTHS'] > 3] = pd.np.nan`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski make this an answer and I will make it as correct. Funny how easy it is

Comment: @StevenRumbalski do not chain indexing like that. Instead do `df.loc[df[...]>3, 'TOTAL'] = np.nan`.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Just figured that out from the docs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['COUNT_MONTHS'] > 3, 'TOTAL'] = np.nan
```

Edit:

My initial thought was to propose:

```
df['TOTAL'][df['COUNT_MONTHS'] > 3] = np.nan
```

This is referred to as chained-indexing or chained-assignment.  It works here but there are three reasons avoid it.

1. It is not idiomatic and therefore less readable to others.
2. It is less efficient.
3. In more complicated situations it may not actually update your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, x in df['COUNT_MONTHS']:   
    if x < 3:   
       df.loc[index, 'TOTAL'] = np.nan  
    else:
       df.loc[index, 'TOTAL'] = 'MY_THING'
```

Working example:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
>>>for index, x in df['a'].items():
    if x <3 :
        df.loc[index,'total'] = np.nan
    else:
        df.loc[index,'total'] = 10
>>>df

    a   total
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
2   3   100.0
3   4   100.0
4   5   100.0
5   6   100.0
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (I guess I need some help with my index to use this.)

Comment: Working just fine for me. Can you please post where you are getting this error? Or provide data for df

Answer (score -2):

You can use apply function with if else condition.

```
df['Total'] =  df['COUNT_MONTHS'].apply(lambda x : np.nan if x > 3 else ??)
```

Comment: This does solve OP's question. Suggesting different method.

Comment: What's wrong is his question is what to put for those question marks in the else.  Since he doesn't want the total to change he would need to return the total, but the function is receiving only the count. You've simply given the OP a second situation in which the same problem arises.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks for explaining. Now I understood it correctly.